# How to pass javascript array value to the python flask

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, web, flask

I have a html form it generates array of values after submitting, I want to pass those array of values to python flask.

I tried using hidden form with field **id="Result"**. But flask not recognizing id it only taking value from name filed.

I don't know what to do, I'm new to the Flask framework.

Here is my javascript code:

```js
function add_element_to_array()
{
     array[x] = ([
         document.getElementById("user").value,
         document.getElementById("customer").value,
         document.getElementById("product").value,
         document.getElementById("start").value,
         document.getElementById("end").value,
         document.getElementById("status").value,
         document.getElementById("description").value
     ]);
     alert("Element: " + array[x] + " Added at index " + x);
     x++;
         document.getElementById("user").value = "";
         document.getElementById("customer").value = "";
         document.getElementById("product").value = "";
         document.getElementById("start").value = "";
         document.getElementById("end").value = "";
         document.getElementById("status").value = "";
         document.getElementById("description").value = "";
}

function display_array()
{
   var e = "<hr/>";
   //var myJsonString;

   for (var y=0; y<array.length; y++)
   {
     e += "Element " + y + " = " + array[y] + "<br/>";
     //myJsonString = JSON.stringify(array[y]);
     //console.log(myJsonString)
       //return array[y];
   }

   document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e;
}

</script>
```

```html
<form action="/flaskprocess" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" id="Result" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to process  this **document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e;** to flask. I tried many ways but didn't get.

Please Help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this.It is quit simple after set values to hidden type id, give the **name** **attribute** to your hidden field.this will help you

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="Result">
document.getElementById("Result").value = e;
```

this will  set your array values to hidden type id.

```
flask.py
values=request.form.getlist('hidden')
```